# AutoCompleteTextView unselectable drop down items

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have created a new application with **Scrollable Tabs + Swipe**, I start with the auto-generated code.
The activity `extends FragmentActivity` so I'm obviously using `Fragment` in my project

The user taps an item in the menu which takes the user to another tab, like so

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(SectionsPagerAdapter.FRAGMENT_INDEX, true);
```

This tab isn't visible until the user selects the menu item

A new `Fragment` is instantiated, with the appropriate layout file, which, currently, just contains an `AutoCompleteTextView` and a `RelativeLayout`. This is how I set up the `ArrayAdapter`:

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.fragment_layout, R.id.auto_complete_text_view, arrayData);
```

and then set the adapter on the `AutoCompleteTextView`. 
Everything works fine, I get the suggestions in the drop down, but the problem I am currently facing is that when I tap the drop down item, nothing happens. The `AutoCompleteTextView` doesn't get populated with the selected drop down item.
I noticed that the when I select the drop down item I get the "blinking line".

I have tried creating my own `AutoCompleteTextView` and using different contexts, but I am getting the same results

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahaha, OK, so my mistake was when I was setting up the `ArrayAdapter` I was using the layout ID of my fragment, but I changed it to `android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line` and is now working perfectly fine =]]